# count the letters of the words within a string

Tags: javascript

So I am new to JavaScript - can't seem to find a solution to this simple challenge.

If I am to parse the following into `str = "apple ban"`

It must return the following in an `array = ["apple 5", "ban 3"]`

Basically - count recognise the words, count the amount of letters in each word, split the string whenever a white space comes up and push this into an array with each word separated and the length of each word next to it.

This is my workings so far - why off base.

```
function addLength(str){

  var array = [];

  array.push(str.split(/\s+/).length);

  return array;
}
```

I have looked through past questions on SoF and tried to make my own conclusions / solution. doesn't seem to be the case this time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this

```
var str = "apple ban";
var strArr = str.split(" ").map(x => {
  return x + " " + x.length;
});
console.log(strArr);
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2wfrxshh/10/)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you Anik - that worked perfectly. map() function I need to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var name = "boss";
var obj = {};
var newArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
  var count = 0;
  for (var j = 0; j < name.length; j++) {
    if (name.charAt(i) === name.charAt(j)) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  
  var result = name[i] + "-" + count;
  obj = Object.assign(result);
  newArray.push(obj);
}

console.log(newArray);
```

output:

```
[ "b-1", "o-1", "s-2", "s-2" ]
```

Comment: Please add some text to explain your solution. At least in a way so that the questions author can follow.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "annnu";
var arr = str.split("");
var count = 1;
var map1 = new Map();

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (map1.has(arr[i])) {
    var k = map1.get(arr[i]);
    map1.set(arr[i], ++k);
  } else {
    map1.set(arr[i], 1);
  }
}

for (var [key, value] of map1) {
  console.log(key + ' = ' + value);
}
```